# Override Eclipse Metadata API Version

Tags: ide, metadata-api, eclipse

Is it possible to override the eclipse metadata api version?  Often new details are available via the metadata api before the latest eclipse ide update (assuming that they actually include new stuff in the eclipse plugin).  For example, I'd like to download tab visibilities for a permission set, but no matter what I do, the api version keeps rolling back to 24 (the current version of the plugin I have installed).

I've tried the following

- Updated endpointApiVersion in .settings/com.salesforce.ide.core.prefs
- Updated ideVersion in .settings/com.salesforce.ide.core.prefs
- Updated metadataFormatVersion in .settings/com.salesforce.ide.core.prefs
- Updated version in project package.xml

I know I can work around this using ANT, but would love to hear if the community had any suggestions for working around version gaps in the eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is not possible with Eclipse.  If you want to pull metadata for a recent release before the latest Eclipse upgrade is release you need to use the Metadata API directly either via ANT or another tool (i.e. metaforce gem).

Answer (score 0):

I just go directly to the class metadata files (ClassName.cls-meta.xml), change the API version  there and save it. It's a bit of a pain but you can do a ctrl+h to search and replace all versions, for example by globally replacing 20.0 with 26.0.[image: metadata]

Comment: This still won't solve the problem of pulling v26 metadata from an org with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. It took me a while, but I was able to upgrade finally.

I followed the update directions on the force.com developer website through the force.com start page: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Updating_the_Force.com_IDE

I thought the update had completed successfully, but it took longer than expected. Make sure to check the Available Software screen (Help > Install New Software > What is already installed?)

[image]

Then verify that force.com IDE is version 26:

[image]

If you see version 24, you may need to re-update. I did it through the Install Software instead of the force.com start page (Help > Install New Software):

[image]

Once done updating the IDE, you still need to go into the prefs and change the endpoint to 26 as well as package.xml of the force.com project you're working on. Once you hit save it will ask you to upgrade it to Winter '13. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the detail.  I've upgraded since then, the issue was that there is often a gap between when the eclipse plugin upgrade is released and when the release occurs.  I'm trying to get the plugin to use the new api version even though it hasn't been upgraded.  By comparison ANT can easily query metadata in api 26 even if your library is api 24/25

Comment: you can also use the free workbench tool: http://workbench.developerforce.com - there's a metadata retrieve and deploy option in the menu.

Comment: totally, ant also works, i've got source control and a bunch of other plug-ins in eclipse.  was trying to get this done within eclipse, which unfortunately looks like it's not possible until the upgrade is released

Comment: Makes sense. So the short answer to your original question is 'no' then - until salesforce releases an update to the Force.com IDE, you can't actually develop in the IDE under the new version of the MdAPI. I believe there are plans to make this easier to manage but currently, it's a limitation of working with Eclipse right now.

Comment: Yep, although it's not a limitation of eclipse, just the plugin design being tied to a specific api version.  Ant seems to work just fine downloading future api versions with older ant libraries